# Trying to upload tiffs to Mapbox I get 'Access denied when calling the CreateMultipartUpload operation'

Tags: linux, shell, curl, mapbox, aws-cli

I am trying to create a shell script that will upload our tiffs to mapbox using their API. I retrieve the temporary credentials from the initial curl post but when it comes to copying the data across via aws' cp command I get the error Access denied when calling the CreateMultipartUpload operation.

I am assuming that this error is to do with credentials being stored incorrectly. My code is as follows:

```
#save curl response as var
ans=`curl -X POST "https://api.mapbox.com/uploads/v1/xxx/credentials?access_token=$token"`

#extract necessary info from var
key=`echo $ans | grep -zoP '"key":\s*"\K[^\s,]*(?=\s*",)'`
bucket=`echo $ans | grep -zoP '"bucket":\s*"\K[^\s,]*(?=\s*",)'`
accessKeyId=`echo $ans | grep -zoP '"accessKeyId":\s*"\K[^\s,]*(?=\s*",)'`
secretAccessKey=`echo $ans | grep -zoP '"secretAccessKey":\s*"\K[^\s,]*(?=\s*",)'`
sessionToken=`echo $ans | grep -zoP '"sessionToken":\s*"\K[^\s,]*(?=\s*",)'`

#export env variables for auth
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$accessKeyId
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$secretAccessKey
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$sessionToken

#copy data across
aws s3 cp $inputdir s3://$bucket/$key/ --recursive --region us-east-1
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`--recursive` is not supported. You need to upload file one by one.

Comment: I have just tried removing --recursive and wrapping it in an for loop but I get exactly the same error.